# Left-Handed Helical Fletching

Tags: bow-hunting

When you are fletching your arrows does a lefty shoot with a left helix in their fletching or is it still at a right helix?  The reason I ask is the most common fletching tools are to give a right helix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will not matter which way the fletching runs on arrows for left or right handed archers, however right handed fletching tools will be harder for a left hander to use, as you would need to change the angle of your hand.

Any angling of the fletching will produce spin on the arrow, however this is not going to affect the shot of a right or left hander, for the simple fact that once it leaves the bow, the spin direction is irrelevant, and during that first short time between releasing the arrow and it passing beyond the bow, there should not be any spin on the arrow.